# Count ID based on start date

Tags: count, sas

I have a source table that looks like this

I start counting ID of the Pd based on the first date then go to the 2nd date and check if it is Pd the add the ID, the go the 3rd date and check if Pd from the previous date are change or not if the change the count them to new group. Please see the desired output. Could you please help?

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain in more detail the counting algorithm ? For `02-07` why did `Pd` go from `3` to `2` ? For rows that do not have `Pd` are you 'stacking' the NG and G counts, and unstacking them as new `Pd` show up ?

Comment: Why did you delete your data after you had an answer? That doesn't support the concept of answering questions on SO to create a body of knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a single pass solution you will need to track **each ids** prior `inv`.  When this tracking is in place you will

- decrement an `inv`s count based on ids prior `inv`
- increment an `inv`s count based on ids current `inv`
- in the tracker replace the ids prior `inv` with the current `inv`

The number of ids is dynamic and not known apriori, and ids prior `inv` value lookup is keyed on id.  The best DATA Step feature for dynamic lookup is `HASH`

Also, because the counts output is a pivot based on `inv` values, you will need to either

- have a series of if/then or select/when statements to increment/decrement the `inv`s counts
- output data as `date` `inv` `count` and `Proc TRANSPOSE`

**Data**

```
data have; 
format id 4. date yymmdd10. inv $2.;
input id date yymmdd10. event $ e_seq inv ; datalines;
100 2018-01-01  In  1   Pd
101 2018-01-01  In  1   Pd
102 2018-02-04  In  1   Pd
100 2018-02-07  N   2   NG
101 2018-02-14  P   2   G
101 2018-02-18  A   3   Pd
100 2018-03-15  A   3   Pd
102 2018-05-01  P   2   G
103 2018-06-03  In  1   Pd
run;
```

**Sample code**

Nested DOW loops are used to test for end of input data and ensure one row output for each date (the group)

```
data want(keep=date G NG Pd);
  if 0 then set have; * prep pdv for hash;

  * ids is the 'tracker';
  declare hash ids(); 
  ids.defineKey('id');
  ids.defineData('id', 'lastinv');
  ids.defineDone();

  lastinv = inv; * prep lastinv in pdv;

  do until (end);
    do until (last.date);

      set have end=end;
      where inv in ('Pd' 'G' 'NG');
      by date;

      if ids.find() = 0 then do; * decrement count based on ids prior inv;
        select (lastinv);
          when ('G')  G  + -1;
          when ('NG') NG + -1;
          when ('Pd') Pd + -1;
          otherwise ;
        end;    
      end;

      * update ids prior inv;

      lastinv = inv;
      ids.replace();

      * increment count based on ids prior inv;

      select (lastinv);
        when ('G')  G  + 1;
        when ('NG') NG + 1;
        when ('Pd') Pd + 1;
        otherwise ;
      end;

    end;
    OUTPUT;  * <------------ output one row of counts per date;
  end;
run;
```